# Force Text Input Labels To Wrap

Tags: css, material-design-lite

I'm working on a layout based on Google's MDL.
We have a requirement for longer input labels than stock MDL apparently allows.

I've managed to get the text to wrap successfully, and reposition the label appropriately for the default state, but it breaks the focus classes and doesn't float properly.

To get the label showing up in the correct position, I modified `.mdl-textfield__label` to be absolutely position based on the bottom, instead of the top.

```
.mdl-textfield__label {
  bottom: 24px;
  /* top: 24px;  Removed This Line */
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36);
  font-size: 16px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: normal;
  text-align: left; }
```

Curious if anyone else has managed to implement similar behavior.

[image: The floating text issue]

Comment: It will be better if you post a JSfiddle to recreate the problem, so that we can understand better

Comment: If you need a long text input why can't you use a `textarea` and hide the with resize grabber with css?

Comment: Its not necessarily the input length that I'm worried about - its the label length.